# Problemas al ejecutar procedimiento almacenado en asp net

Tags: api, asp

Estoy teniendo problemas al ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado

La particularidad es que tengo una solución con dos proyectos
En uno esta la api la cual funciona y me trae los datos en json
Y el otro es un proyecto asp net mvc para las vistas crud

La fuente de datos del segundo proyecto es la misma api
Y tengo un procedimiento almacenado para listar y ese si funciona pero el de guardar y actualizar no

Al llegar a la línea cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
Pareciera que no hace nada
Pero debugeando veo que los datos si llegan

A que se debe?

Comment: marca algún error o por que dices que no hace nada?

Comment: No no marca error solo no devuelve nada y no guarda ni actualiza y al debugear veo que no me hace el punto de interrupcion en el otro proyecto

Comment: De hecho estoy ejecutando primero la api y luego ejecuto el otro proyecto mvc porque como la fuente de datos es la api ya tiene que estar corriendo

Comment: CORS? tu navegador no saca errores en la consola?

Comment: En la consola tampoco muestra nada, es todo un embrollo, pise el punto de interrupción en el proyecto mvc y me fui a ver al de la api y ahí vi que los datos si caen en la clase donde se manda a llamar los procedimientos pero no hace nada, no ejecuta la consulta